# mongo schema creates empty object with id

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to create a new mongo object but the code below returns an empty object with only id. What am I doing wrong, I just can't see the mistake. No errors returned on calling, just an empty object.
This is nest js app

```
    const newComment = new this.commentModel({
      name: user.name,
      avatar: user.avatar,
      user: userId,
      text: text,
    });
```

Here is my schema:

```
Schema();
class Comment {
    @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' })
    user: User;

    @Prop({ required: true })
    text: string;

    @Prop()
    name: string;

    @Prop()
    avatar: string;

    @Prop({ default: Date.now })
    date: Date;
}

export const CommentSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Comment);
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

so there are a couple of things that are off here, first the schema decoration should be  `@Schema` not `Schema`. then you have to export the class itself then finally await the creating results. so putting it all together would be

**creating a new comment **

```
const newComment = await new this.commentModel({
  name: user.name,
  avatar: user.avatar,
  user: userId,
  text: text,
});
```

The schema should now be

```
@Schema();
export class Comment {
    @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' })
    user: User;

    @Prop({ required: true })
    text: string;

    @Prop()
    name: string;

    @Prop()
    avatar: string;

    @Prop({ default: Date.now })
    date: Date;
}

export const CommentSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Comment);
```

if you have a UserSchema which am guessing you do you can change the reference to `User.name` for type-safety this would now look like

```
    @Schema();
    export class Comment {
        @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: User.name })
        user: User;
    
        @Prop({ required: true })
        text: string;
    
        @Prop()
        name: string;
    
        @Prop()
        avatar: string;
    
        @Prop({ default: Date.now })
        date: Date;
    }
export const CommentSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Comment);
```

Comment: Man, you are a lifesaver! I had the same problem and I just could not see it. Wasted sooooo much time! Thank you!!